# Objective-C block "retain cycle" warning, don't understand why

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I've seen several other questions of the same form, but I either a) can't understand the provided answers, or b) don't see how those situations are similar to mine.

I'm writing a Category on UIView to recursively evaluate all the subviews of a UIView and return an Array of subviews passing a test.  I've noted where my compiler warning occurs:

```
-(NSArray*)subviewsPassingTest:(BOOL(^)(UIView *view, BOOL *stop))test {

   __block BOOL *stop = NO;

    NSArray*(^__block evaluateAndRecurse)(UIView*);
    evaluateAndRecurse = ^NSArray*(UIView *view) {
        NSMutableArray *myPassedChildren = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (UIView *subview in [view subviews]) {
            BOOL passes = test(subview, stop);
            if (passes) [myPassedChildren addObject:subview];
            if (stop) return myPassedChildren;


            [myPassedChildren addObjectsFromArray:evaluateAndRecurse(subview)];
            // ^^^^ Compiler warning here ^^^^^
            // "Capturing 'evaluateAndRecurse' strongly in this block 
            // is likely to lead to a retrain cycle"
        }
        return myPassedChildren;
    };

    return evaluateAndRecurse(self);
}
```

Also, I get a bad_access failure when I don't include the `__block` modifier in my block's declaration `(^__block evaluateAndRecurse)`.  If someone could explain why that is, that would be very helpful too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that your block `evaluteAndRecurse()` captures itself, which means that, if it's ever to be copied (I don't believe it will in your case, but in slightly less-trivial cases it may), then it will retain itself and therefore live forever, as there is nothing to break the retain cycle.

**Edit**: Ramy Al Zuhouri made a good point, using `__unsafe_unretained` on the only reference to the block is dangerous. As long as the block remains on the stack, this will work, but if the block needs to be copied (e.g. it needs to escape to a parent scope), then the `__unsafe_unretained` will cause it to be deallocated. The following paragraph has been updated with the recommended approach:

What you probably want to do here is use a separate variable marked with `__unsafe_unretained` that also contains the block, and capture that separate variable. This will prevent it from retaining itself. You could use `__weak`, but since you know that the block must be alive if it's being called, there's no need to bother with the (very slight) overhead of a weak reference. This will make your code look like

```
NSArray*(^__block __unsafe_unretained capturedEvaluteAndRecurse)(UIView*);
NSArray*(^evaluateAndRecurse)(UIView*) = ^NSArray*(UIView *view) {
    ...
        [myPassedChildren addObjectsFromArray:capturedEvaluateAndRecurse(subview)];
};
capturedEvaluateAndRecurse = evaluteAndRecurse;
```

Alternatively, you could capture a pointer to the block, which will have the same effect but allow you to grab the pointer before the block instantiation instead of after. This is a personal preference. It also allows you to omit the `__block`:

```
NSArray*(^evaluateAndRecurse)(UIView*);
NSArray*(^*evaluteAndRecursePtr)(UIView*) = &evaluateAndRecurse;
evaluateAndRecurse = ^NSArray*(UIView*) {
    ...
        [myPassedChildren addObjectsFromArray:(*evaluateAndRecursePtr)(subview)];
};
```

---

As for needing the `__block`, that's a separate issue. If you don't have `__block`, then the block instance will actually capture the *previous value* of the variable. Remember, when a block is created, any captured variables that aren't marked with `__block` are actually stored as a `const` copy of their state at the point where the block is instantiated. And since the block is created *before* it's assigned to the variable, that means it's capturing the state of the `capturedEvaluteAndRecurse` variable before the assignment, which is going to be `nil` (under ARC; otherwise, it would be garbage memory).

In essence, you can think of a given block instance as actually being an instance of a hidden class that has an ivar for each captured variable. So with your code, the compiler would basically treat it as something like:

```
// Note: this isn't an accurate portrayal of what actually happens
PrivateBlockSubclass *block = ^NSArray*(UIView *view){ ... };
block->stop = stop;
block->evaluteAndRecurse = evaluateAndRecurse;
evaluteAndRecurse = block;
```

Hopefully this makes it clear why it captures the previous value of `evaluateAndRecurse` instead of the current value.

Comment: Why doesn't the ARC retain count go to zero after the assignment of evaluateAndRecurse?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: Retain count of what?

Comment: Of the block, since the block is __unsafe_unretained, shouldn't been deallocated after the assignment?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: That's actually a good point. It's a bit ambiguous what's going on here. Technically yes, it could be deallocated after assignment, but it's actually on the stack at this point, and retain/release doesn't do anything to stack blocks (they need to be copied first). Which basically means the compiler is actually free to do whatever it wants with this stack block. It seems clang is persisting the stack block to the end of the current scope, but technically it could discard it immediately. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: Actually, I take it back. I think the compiler has to persist the stack block until the reference goes away, just like any non-object stack value. But my recommendation is still dangerous for more complicated code that requires copying the block, so I'll update it anyway.

Comment: this is all assuming he is using ARC

Comment: `__unsafe_unretained` is precisely what should be used here. Nothing dangerous about it.

Comment: @newacct: If the block is copied, and the only reference to it is `__unsafe_unretained`, then it's going to be released immediately.

Comment: @newacct: And of course he's using ARC, the retain cycle warning only exists under ARC.

Comment: "that means it's capturing the state of the evaluteAndRecurse variable before the assignment" - don't you mean "captureEvaluateAndRecurse" in that phrase?

Comment: @HariKaramSingh: Good catch, yes I do.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar, but in a different way to cut down on time allocating new arrays, and haven't had any problems.  You could try adapting your method to look something like this:

```
- (void)addSubviewsOfKindOfClass:(id)classObject toArray:(NSMutableArray *)array {

    if ([self isKindOfClass:classObject]) {

        [array addObject:self];
    }

    NSArray *subviews = [self subviews];
    for (NSView *view in subviews) {

        [view addSubviewsOfKindOfClass:classObject toArray:array];
    }
}
```